# MySQL Query Giving Duplicates Due to Different Dates

Tags: mysql, sql

This query is giving exactly what it is asking for but the problem is that it is not what I want and I can't seem to get rid of duplicates and other posts on the subject do not seem applicable. It is for a sales report and it pulls the date from the calendar but sometimes the same sale has more than one calendar event when a call-back was needed.

The calendar table has only ID, Title, Location, Start, Quote fields with the rest being from quoterequests and this is MySQL.

```
SELECT qr.ID AS ID, 
c.ID AS CalendarID, 
DATE_FORMAT(QuoteDate,'%m-%d-%Y') AS QuoteDate, 
DATE_FORMAT(`Start`,'%m-%d-%Y') AS VerDate, 
TIME_FORMAT(`Start`,'%h:%i %p') AS VerTime, 
Name, MakeModel, CONCAT_WS('-',Prefix, Telephone) AS Phone, 
Email, 
Address, 
City, 
State, 
Zipcode, 
MilesQuoted, 
AmtQuoted, 
AmtCharged, 
ServiceFee 
FROM quoterequests qr 

JOIN calendar c 
ON Quote = qr.ID 

WHERE AmtCharged > 0 
AND YEAR(`Start`) = 2015 
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Start`) ASC
```

Comment: While there's not really anything wrong with it,  note that no one actually uses RIGHT JOIN. But the more serious issue is your inclusion of a GROUP BY clause in a query absent of any aggregating functions. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It seems like you need to group by quote id but not calendar id. You can then use MIN(`Start`) to get the first calendar record's start

Comment: I meant to remove the RIGHT from the JOIN before posting as I don't generally use it either. I was trying variations to see if any made a different but all were the same. The other ideas are worth a try so I'll post back if any success.

Comment: So your quoterequests and calendar table is a OneToMany relation, then you must let the aggregator know which date to pick, MIN or MAX.

Answer (score 0):

Not really enough information to answer the question, but as a rule of thumb:

GROUP BY is used only when you mix aggragate functions (min, max, count etc) with normal columns. It is not meant to be used to remove duplicates.

To remove duplicates use `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: Unfortunately DISTINCT does not work in this case because even with the duplicates, the resulting rows are distinct due to the two different calendar dates. I was hoping that someone would spot something simple that was missed but maybe it will have to be done with a sub-query.

Comment: if you can provide some sample data (sqlfiddle), it would be much easier to help.

Comment: Happy to but not sure how to fetch the data into a presentable format for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps unnecessarily convoluted but this seems to do the trick and while I was at it I realized that Quote is apparently a reserved word so I back-ticked it. It turned out that the main problem, as pointed out, was the lack of MIN but I didn't realize that it could be used in multiple places. Once I did that, it gave the proper results:

```
SELECT 
        ID,
        DATE_FORMAT(QuoteDate,'%m-%d-%Y') AS QuoteDate,
        DATE_FORMAT(MIN(c.`Start`),'%m-%d-%Y') AS VerDate,
        TIME_FORMAT(MIN(c.`Start`),'%h:%i %p') AS VerTime,

        Name, MakeModel, CONCAT_WS('-',Prefix, Telephone) AS Phone,
        Email,
        Address,
        City,
        State,
        Zipcode,
        MilesQuoted,
        AmtQuoted,
        AmtCharged,
        ServiceFee

FROM quoterequests qr 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT `Quote`, 
                `Start`, 
                MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Start`)) AS `TimeStamp`
                FROM calendar c
                WHERE YEAR(`Start`) = 2015 
                GROUP BY ID, `Quote`, `Start` 
                ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Start`) ASC) AS c 
        ON qr.ID = c.`Quote` 
WHERE AmtCharged > 0 
AND YEAR(c.`Start`) = 2015 
GROUP BY `Quote` 
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(c.`Start`)) ASC
```